# How would one compute the heterotic amplitude for four gauginos using bosonization?

Tags: particle-physics, string-theory, supersymmetry, bosonization

I'm reading through Polchinski's *String Theory Volume II*, and I was unsure of how to approach Problem 12.9. For posterity, the problem states:

> Calculate the tree-level heterotic string amplitude with four gauginos. You can either do this directly, or by first calculating an appropriate bosonic open string amplitude and then using the open-closed relation.

The open-closed relation is (12.4.29) in the book:
$$A_c(s,t,u,\alpha',g_c) = -\frac{i \pi g_c^2\alpha'}{g_o^4}A_o(s,t,\frac{1}{4}\alpha',g_o)A_o(t,u,\frac{1}{4}\alpha',g_o)^* \sin(\frac{\pi \alpha' t}{4})$$

The direct calculation generally makes sense to me (all of the expectation values for the components of the vertex factors for Type I strings and for the current algebra part of the heterotic vertex factor are found at various points in the chapter), but I am unsure of how to do this using the latter approach.